# posix written through rodbc into mysql database gets truncated

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc

When I write a column of class POSIXct into a MySQL database using RODBC it gets truncated to only the year. 
This happens for example with:

```
sqlSave(connection, dat = data.frame(date = as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 08:10:00")+0:10*60), 
    tablename = "date_column")
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot why I decided not to use it. What advantages does RMySQL have over RODBC other than that it is easier to set up?

Comment: In theory, should be quite a bit faster because RMySQL talks directly to MySQL instead of going through a third party. Not sure how much of a practical different it makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to make the column of type datetime in mysql explicitly like this:

```
library(RODBC)
con <- odbcConnect("mysql", uid="root", case = "tolower")
(dat <- data.frame(date = Sys.time()))
#                  date
# 1 2015-03-08 23:55:33
res <- sqlSave(con, dat = dat, varTypes = c("date" = "datetime"), tablename = "date_column")
close(con)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the solution! Thanks! It might be also worth pointing out that "date" has to be spelled like it will be named in the sql table and not like in the data.frame, if there is a difference (e.g. Date becomes date).